# How to call FormClose event handler?

Tags: delphi

I try to call the method FormClose, but I have a problem with its parameters when I try:

```
FormName.FormClose(nil, CaFree);
```

Normally I can call a component's event handler with a parameter using `nil` or `sender as TOBject`. But now I get the error:

> Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter

I have tried many combinations for these two TObject and TAction values. For TObject I tried `sender as TObject', and for TAction all parameters like CaFree etc.

Comment: `FormClose` is an event handler. It is almost always a mistake to call it yourself. You should just be calling `Close` (which is intended just for that use). If you need to free the form, there are much more appropriate ways to do so.

Comment: Yes, but because of very specific nature of project i can close Form without  close a ParentForm, ParentForm.onclose have many functions because of data . My problem has been solved below anyway thank you for your attention.

Comment: You can close a form without closing its parent form without calling FormClose. As I said, if you're finding the need to do this you're probably doing something very wrong. David's answer may solve your immediate problem, but doing the wrong thing and finding a hacky fix usually means more problems in the future. You should be doing things properly in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter is a `var` parameter which is what the compiler error message is telling you. So you need to pass a variable. You cannot pass a literal.

```
var
  Action: TCloseAction;
....
Action := caFree;
Name.FormClose(nil, Action);
```

Note that you almost certainly should not be doing this. You are not meant to call event handlers directly. The framework will call them at the appropriate time. I think it exceedingly likely that you are mistaken in thinking that you need to fire this event handler directly, or even execute the code outside the normal scenario of the form closing.

As a general rule, if you need to invoke code in an event handler directly then the normal approach is to first extract it to a separate method which can readily be called directly. Then refactor the event handler to call that separate method.

Comment: Thank you, that anwser help me solution problem. 
What other method Parameters of it is also necessary to prescribe a variable?

Comment: You need to pass a variable for `var` and `out` parameters. Other parameters can accept any expression of the correct type, or an expression that can be implicitly cast to the correct type.